# Shopping Cart For Non-Members

Tags: php, session, cookies, shopping-cart

I have a e-commerce (PHP) system. And it is working now. I decided to allow non-members can order. I'm using session for userid. And i'm storing data in database. But how can i do it for non-members ?

Using Cookie or Session. I couldn't decide it. What is your offer ? Should i store all data in cookie ? Or in database ?

Answer (score 1):

I would store all of the data in the session up until the final step of your order flow and then save the order and customer data to the database.

Cookies only allow around 4kb of data storage and while it is possible to use multiple cookies on a site to increase the total storage space, generally you would store data on the server and only store an identifier in the cookie to retrieve the data.  This is how cookie based sessions work as well which is the default session handling type in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Storing data in a cookie requires that the user has cookies activated. Store the data in the session.

Comment: Do you mean storing all data in session or only storing special ID as userid and saving all data in database. When session is destroyed, destroy everyting.

Comment: My main point is, don't use cookies to store the shopping cart. Storing the userid in the session and using that to reference database entries might prove difficult, considering that anonymous users either don't have a userid or share a userid with other anonymous users.